# Sparql - owlim query does not work after update

Tags: rdf, sesame

I've created application, which works with openrdf sesame and owlim module. Recently, I needed to update licence key to owlim (I recieved key for newest owlim version), so I was forced to update sesame as well.

Application was build with sesame 2.6.0 and owlim 4.3, now updated to sesame 2.6.8 and owlim 5.2

I have problem with sparql query, which uses owlim module.

```
PREFIX geo: <http ://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX opgeo: <http ://something.com/OPropertiesGeo#>
PREFIX opnet: <http ://something.com/OPropertiesNet#>
PREFIX omgeo: <http ://www.ontotext.com/owlim/geo#>

SELECT  (?doorwayID as ?address) ?longitude ?latitude ?mobile ?streetName ?houseNumber WHERE {

    ?doorwayID geo:long ?longitude . 
    ?doorwayID geo:lat ?latitude . 
    ?doorwayID opnet:mobile ?mobile .  
    ?specialzoneID geo:lat ?centerlat . 
    ?specialzoneID geo:long ?centerlong . 
    ?specialzoneID geo:radius ?radius . 
    ?doorwayID omgeo:nearby(?centerlat ?centerlong ?radius) . 
    ?doorwayID opgeo:street ?streetID . 
    ?streetID opgeo:name ?streetName . 
    OPTIONAL { ?doorwayID opgeo:houseNumber ?houseNumber . } 

}
```

This should select every point in area defined in nearby function - ?doorwayID omgeo:nearby(?centerlat ?centerlong ?radius) . , problem is that result set is empty.

I think this is related to my previous post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780014/sparql-delete-queries-stop-working-after-update/11787809#11787809), but after two hours of trying and googling I still does not discover right solution :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After upgrading, did you recreate your geo-spatial index using:

PREFIX ontogeo: http://www.ontotext.com/owlim/geo#
INSERT DATA { _:b1 ontogeo:createIndex _:b2. }

?